# Use build parameter in downstream build configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Parameterized Trigger Plugin on my Jenkins server and I am trying to use a pre-defined parameter used while triggering my downstream build. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work the way I want so I wanted to see if someone could point out what I am doing wrong. Here is my parameterized trigger:

[image: Parameterized trigger]

And here is where I try to consume the build parameter in a downstream build:
[image: Consume build parameter]

However, this does not seem to work an the project name shows up as blank when the build gets triggered. Is this doable? Am I doing this right? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are documented issues of this type of behavior in Jenkins version 2.3

However, the following worked for me:
You need to extend your triggered/downstream jobs (every "Job B") to accept additional parameters. Enable in project B the option "This project is parameterized" and add parameters with the same name as the one passed by the project A.

Comment: I tried this by adding a string parameter to my downstream job with the same name as the predefined parameter from the upstream job. However, the variable still shows as blank when it is triggered. Any other ideas to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I am mistaken. I must of had something configured wrong because this is actually working! Thanks!